Place each proof on its own page in appendix
In my document, I am wanting some of my proofs to live in the body of the text, and others to be deferred to an appendix, along with their corresponding theorem statements. In attempt to do this, I am using proof-at-the-end, as it allows me to automatically restate the theorems. However, within this appendix, I am also wanting each proof to live on its own page, or rather, for a new page to start after every proof in the appendix.
I tried redefining the qed symbol to be qed followed by a \newpage, but this doesn't work because I still have some proofs in the main body that I don't want to be isolated. I can't manually insert a \newpage between every proof because they are all displayed from \printProofs (though a general solution would be nice anyway). I'd also prefer not to copy/paste the theorem statements at the end in case the wording of the theorem statements changes. If it comes to it, I could create a new environment for each theorem and manually restate each of them in the appendix one by one, but again, a more general solution would be nice.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{proof-at-the-end}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newEndThm[restate, text link={The proof is in the appendix.}, no link to theorem]{appendixTheorem}{theorem}
\newEndProof{appendixProof}

\begin{document}
\section{Main text}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    This is its proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{appendixTheorem}
    This is a theorem for the appendix.
\end{appendixTheorem}
\begin{appendixProof}
    This is the proof in the appendix.
    There should be no more text on this page after this proof ends.
\end{appendixProof}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a third theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    This is a proof in the main text again.
\end{proof}

\begin{appendixTheorem}
    This is yet another appendix theorem.
\end{appendixTheorem}
\begin{appendixProof}
    This proof should also be in the appendix, but (along with the theorem statement) should be on a separate page from the proof of Theorem 2.
\end{appendixProof}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a fifth and final theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    This is a fifth and final proof.
\end{proof}

\newpage
\section{Appendix}
\printProofs

\end{document}

I'm not tied to using proof-at-the-end, but this has been the best option so far.

easy, reliable solution: each proof in its own file and \input{} at will. this also makes it possible to use the same input in multiple documents e.g. a handout for a talk, slides etc.

or just write them to file as you go. I guess this is probably what the package does anyway?

Given that it's the theorem that needs restating (the proofs only appear once), I would put the theorems in their own files instead, and the proofs could be in the main document. However, the appendix is going to be quite large (a lot of proofs), so if possible I'd prefer to limit the number of files. Thanks for your suggestion though!

The \printProofs command is loading a file containing proof environments, so we can just add \newpage to the env/proof/after hook.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{proof-at-the-end}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newEndThm[restate, text link={The proof is in the appendix.}, no link to theorem]{appendixTheorem}{theorem}
\newEndProof{appendixProof}

\begin{document}
\section{Main text}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    This is its proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{appendixTheorem}
    This is a theorem for the appendix.
\end{appendixTheorem}
\begin{appendixProof}
    This is the proof in the appendix.
    There should be no more text on this page after this proof ends.
\end{appendixProof}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a third theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    This is a proof in the main text again.
\end{proof}

\begin{appendixTheorem}
    This is yet another appendix theorem.
\end{appendixTheorem}
\begin{appendixProof}
    This proof should also be in the appendix, but (along with the theorem statement) should be on a separate page from the proof of Theorem 2.
\end{appendixProof}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a fifth and final theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    This is a fifth and final proof.
\end{proof}

\newpage
\section{Appendix}
\AddToHook{env/proof/after}{\newpage}
\printProofs

\end{document}




